# How to properly read POST params with express?

Tags: express, npm-request

My node app is supposed to POST to an external server, so I'm playing with `request` from NPM. I want to verify it's working, but I'm not entirely sure I'm doing that right.

I've tried both of these methods

```
request({
  url: url,
  method: 'POST',
  form: { a: 1}
}

request({
  url: url,
  method: 'POST',
  json: true,
  body: { a: 1}
}
```

In my test when I hit my own server, `req.body` shows the right object when I do `json` true. However that just means I'm passing a JSON header. The API I actually need to hit is expecting a normal POST, not JSON.

So when I try to verify that `request` is working right when I use `form`, my server says `req.body` is an empty object.

**EDIT**
I am posting to external API fine using `form`, but on my own server, express is leaving `request.body` as empty object.

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you:

```
request.post('http://service.com/upload').form({key:'value'})
```